# Call a PHP Function Dynamically.

Tags: php, function, post, dynamic

I have a simple question, I am currently handling php / ajax requests in the current way.

```
// ajax_requests.php

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['ajaxvar'] == 'send')){
   // send timestamp
 }
 if(isset($_POST['ajaxvar'] == 'get')){
   // return get
 }
?>
```

Is there a better way of coping with these requests? Other than this somewhat bloated way of handling with requests.

Comment: Where is your `jQuery` code? What have you tried?

Comment: You could have different pages for requests. I tend to keep my pages and ajax functions to a 1:1 ratio.

Comment: you could have functions and use `call_user_func()`

Comment: Thanks arxanas I try to keep it this way but i either end up with loads of PHP files or a few PHP files handling ajax requests in the aforementioned way. Is there a better way of handling multiple requests from one PHP file?

Comment: improving current design: you could make sure `$_POST['ajaxvar']` is set and then use a `switch` construct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you name your functions after the values you post in 'ajaxvars' then you can run them like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['ajaxvars'])) $_POST['ajaxvars']();

function send(){
    // send timestamp
}

function get(){
    // return get
}
```

So if you have $_POST['ajaxvars'] == 'send', the script will run the send() function. Same for get.

It's also a good idea to first check if the posted function exists, so:

```
if (function_exists($_POST['ajaxvars'])) $_POST['ajaxvars']();
```